# Can I change a sentence of the adverb of 'Apace' as Apacer in comparative adjective joining 'er'

Tags: adverbs, degree-of-comparison

Can I change a sentence of the adverb of 'Apace' as Apacer in comparative adjective joining '*er*'

For example:

"She continued to work apace but he did apacer than her"

I really looked for it in many English dictionaries but I couldn't find it. Do you think that it works in comparison?

Comment: It's hard to get rid of false positives in a Google search. We might have to let OED have a near-final say, but I'd avoid it like the plague. In any case, 'more apace' might be the expected form, if any. The adverb is old-fashioned in most contexts, and becoming frozen in set expressions. I'd guess that even OED doesn't list it.

Comment: Absolutely not. For a start, _apace_ is a rather rare adverb, which is only used in restricted contexts (you couldn't say "walk apace" for example: it only applies to continuing processes). Secondly, the use of _-er_ as a comparative is barely productive (i.e. it is not an ending you can freely add, especially to adverbs). "Apaacer" is not likely to be understood.

Comment: I don't think he ever used 'apacer', but it sounds like a P G Wodehouse word to me. I can imagine Bertie Wooster saying it.

Comment: I can see *apacer* being used tongue-in-cheek in dialog, when the previous speaker used *apace*.  Other than that, no.  Even if it were "a word", it would not be comprehended by 90% of your readers/listeners.

Comment: "Apace" is etymologically a prepositional phrase, as are most adverbs and adjectives that begin with the prefix a-. None of them form the comparative with the ending -er. That said, English is is a living language, and its dictionaries have a preference for description. If your intent is humor, and you can make it work, go for it!

Answer (score 4):

*Apace* has no comparative form.

OED shows its etymology as

> originally phrase *a pace,* like *afoot, ahead,* < **a** prep. of manner + **pace** n.

That is, it came from "at a pace": "*lit.* At a pace, *i.e.* at a considerable or good pace; *hence,* With speed; swiftly, quickly, fast."

Because it means "at a good rate", you can't form **apacer* to improve it. Or at least, it is only admissible in a jocular way — but even then, *apace* is a high-end word which doesn't really lend itself to banter between friends. An exchange such as this is really improbable:

> A: They filled their jar apace.
>   B: But my team did it apacer!

OED does not list *apacer* at all.

Comment: Our team led the race, with theirs a merer chaser.